# EF Power Tools defaulting to pascalcase

Tags: .net-core, json.net, ef-power-tools

We recently adopted EF Power Tools reverse engineering to create our entities in our .Net Core 3 Web Apis.  This has had the unintended consequence of returning data in pascalcase instead of the default camelcase.  I have tried in the `startup.cs`:

```
services.AddMvc.AddJsonOptions(options => options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy =
 JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase)
```

and

```
services.AddNewtonsoftJson(options => options.UseCamelCasing(true))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add the following in your `Configure` section:

```cs
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
};
```